# How to transfer BLOBs to an Oracle database through SQL scripts

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, blob

I'm developing an application which runs on an Oracle database. I'm now in the process of creating an installation package which will contain some SQL scripts containing the default data that comes with the program.

Some of the tables have BLOB columns which need to contain MS Word documents. I'm not sure how to get these BLOBs into the SQL scripts. I know I could do it through Data Pump, but it is a requirement that all database stuff is included in plain text SQL files.

Does anyone know how to get these BLOBs into an SQL script which the client can just run?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the DBMS_LOB and UTL_FILE packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a PHP script that is run as part of the installation process - it loops through all my word documents and inserts them into the database. I would still rather have SQL scripts or something similar but this works for now.